The application build via USB but the apk file is not opening
change the min sdk from 25 to 26
Why after change my minsdk from 25 to 26 my apk build file is not opening . but its still run via USB. there is nothing wrong with my application i try every thing but still its not working some one plz help
here is my gradle build
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {url "https://jitpack.io"}
}

android {
    namespace 'com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample'

    compileSdkVersion 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = rootProject.ext.sourceCompatibilityVersion
        targetCompatibility = rootProject.ext.targetCompatibilityVersion
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.5.2'
    implementation project(path: ':rxandroidble')
    implementation rootProject.ext.libs.appcompat
    implementation rootProject.ext.libs.material_design
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-video:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.1.0"
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:vision-common:17.3.0'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning:18.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-code-scanner:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.3'
    //====== this package is disaster ==========
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition:16.0.0'
    implementation'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning:18.3.0@aar'
    implementation'com.google.mlkit:common:18.10.0@aar'
    implementation'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.3.0@aar'


    implementation'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-components:17.1.5'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.1.0'
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:5.4'


    def room_version = "2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"




//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.1.2'

    //implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'

   // testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
   // androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'

    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
    implementation rootProject.ext.libs.rxandroid
    implementation rootProject.ext.libs.rxjava2
    implementation rootProject.ext.libs.rxjava_binding
    implementation rootProject.ext.libs.rxjava_replayingshare
}

here is my code what should i do should i change my gradle or ...

So if you set it back to 25 it works? Did you check the output of the build script for any indication at what could be wrong? Any logcat output? You're not providing anywhere near to sufficient information.

its install via usb but the apk build file is not opening it got this error App not installed as package appears to be invalid but when i change the minsdk from 26 to 25 every thing back to normal

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

First, check that your Gradle sync and build are completing without errors.
Then, confirm that your AndroidManifest.xml file has the minSdkVersion set to 26 and that your target SDK is set to 26 or higher.
If it still does not work, then look for error messages in Logcat when opening the APK file and add the error messages to the question.

when i wanna install the package i got this error App not installed as package appears to be invalid

check if there are newer versions of the ML Kit components that are compatible with SDK version 26. you can usually find the latest versions in Google's official documentation or on their Maven repository.
also check the AndroidManifest.xml file for any inconsistencies, your error points out that there might be an issue with the APK file itself

but when i change the 26 to 25 the apk file open
